# Get Last Insertion key in JDBCTemplate in update method

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am using

> JdbcTemplate update

method for insertion and I want to get the auto-generated key of the last insertion 
here is my code

```
JdbcTemplate insert = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        int cid = insert.update(
                "INSERT INTO Clinician (name, password) VALUES(?,?)",
                new Object[] { "name",
                        "password" });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [identity from sql insert via jdbctemplate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665846/identity-from-sql-insert-via-jdbctemplate)

Comment: dublicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770877/spring-jdbctemplate-insert-blob-and-return-generated-key

Answer (score 0):

The update() method in JdbcTemplate is taking 2 parameters.
1.String
2.Object[]
But when we call this method by passing a sting and an object, it is executed.

Please explain how it works ?