# Spring JDBC and GeneratedKeyHolder

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I have some code this looks like this sample here (Spring 3.1).  It works just fine.

But I am wondering if there is a more Spring-ish way of returning the key (Oracle nextval) that I just inserted.  Maybe this is the best and only way, but it doesn't seem to be in the spirit of Spring (e.g. less verbosity).

I looked at SimpleJdbcTemplate, but that is deprecated as of 3.1

```
  import java.sql.Connection;
  import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
  import java.sql.SQLException;

  import javax.sql.DataSource;

  import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
  import org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreator;
  import org.springframework.jdbc.support.GeneratedKeyHolder;
  import org.springframework.jdbc.support.KeyHolder;

  public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDao {

          private DataSource dataSource;

          private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

          public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
                  this.dataSource = dataSource;
                  this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(this.dataSource);
          }

          public int insertEmployee() {
                  final String INSERT_SQL = "insert into trn_employee (first_name,last_name) values(?,?)";

                  KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
                  jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
                          public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(
                                          Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                                  PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_SQL,
                                                  new String[] { "employee_id" });
                                  ps.setString(1, "George");
                                  ps.setString(2, "Harrison");
                                  return ps;
                          }
                  }, keyHolder);

                  return keyHolder.getKey().intValue();
          }

  }
```

Comment: Is this what you're after [spring-jdbctemplate-insert-blob-and-return-generated-key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770877/spring-jdbctemplate-insert-blob-and-return-generated-key?rq=1)? The accepted answer seems to state the same wishes. (Dupe?)